# What is the difference between (*p)[8] and *p[8] in C?

Tags: c, programming-languages

The two declarations are as follows:

```
int (*p)[8];
int *p[8];
```

Comment: http://cdecl.org/ is your friend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first is a *single* pointer to an array of 8 integers, while the second is an *array* of 8 pointers, each to an integer.

If you just kick up `cdecl`, it's wonderful for this sort of thing:

```
pax$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help

cdecl> explain int (*p)[8];
declare p as pointer to array 8 of int

cdecl> explain int *p[8];
declare p as array 8 of pointer to int

cdecl> explain char*(*fp[])(int,float*);
declare fp as array of pointer to function (int, pointer to float)
    returning pointer to char
```

There's actually a [clockwise/spiral rule](http://cskill.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/the-clockwisespiral-rule-by-david-anderson/) you can use to do this in your head but I haven't had to worry about that since I discovered `cdecl`, for the same reason I no longer convert large arbitrary 32 bit numbers from decimal to hex in my head any more - I *can* if I have to but it's so much easier with a tool :-)

Comment: I actually prefer C as it's often more clear than english (perhaps because I'm not native speaker).

Answer (score 4):

The first p is a pointer to an array of 8 int.
The second p is an array of 8 pointers to int.

Comment: +1 Also **arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays** :) ... @Hanafuda: read section 6 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/) ... and *welcome to SO*.