# Tool to decipher C/C++ function pointer typedefs

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

I remember once seeing a website, which deciphered complex C++ typedefs including function pointers returning function pointers to functions which return an array with …

It would turn such definitions into readable English text: »Pointer to function, returning an array of int-pointers, taking a long and a callback function (taking an int) as parameters«. (something along that lines)

```
typedef int * (*f)(long, void (*)(int))[];
```

Anybody remember that tool/website? Any hints greatly appreciated

Comment: Interestingly enough, `cdecl` barfs on your example declaration :-) Perhaps you meant `int* (*f)(long, void (*)(int));` which translates to `declare f as pointer to function (long, pointer to function (int) returning void) returning pointer to int`

Comment: By the way, if you want to know how to do this manually (uber-geek), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202203/what-is-the-difference-between-p8-and-p8-in-c/6202269#6202269 which references http://cskill.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/the-clockwisespiral-rule-by-david-anderson/

Comment: @paxdiablo: there was a mistake in my typedef. i corrected it, thanks! (although g++ won't compile it, `error: ‘f’ declared as function returning an array`) — ok, i'd have to return `int **`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for https://cdecl.org/.

You can find the program itself at https://github.com/ridiculousfish/cdecl-blocks

Comment: Looks like it doesn't understand Windows data-types (like HANDLE etc)?

Comment: I haven't used it much myself, but I am guessing it only works with data types that are part of the C standard.

Comment: The link is broken, the same project seems to be hosted at https://cdecl.org/. Verified with wayback machine that they have the same UI - but maybe  http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/ requires some backend service which is down, hence simply replacing the broken link with wayback machine version would be of no help.

Comment: @SahilSingh I adjusted the link. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

The tool is also available under http://cdecl.org