# What does this C statement mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I came across this line:

```
void (*(*x)(void (*[10])(int *)))(int *)
```

Can anybody tell me what it is?

Comment: Is this a quiz or something? :)

Comment: That one's easy to answer: It's a mess.

Comment: The answer is always http://www.cdecl.org.

Comment: @mkb: *"declare x as pointer to function (array 10 of pointer to function (pointer to int) returning void) returning pointer to function (pointer to int) returning void"* - well that clears it up

Comment: Please tell me that you didn't find this in an actual code that actually gets used somehow somewhere ... but rather in an entry of an obfuscated contest of some sort possibly :) ?

Comment: Hey, cdecl.org answers the what, not the why.

Comment: @mkb I don't see the word "why" in the question :)

Comment: This one is the same, only for C++: [Tool to decipher C/C++ function pointer typedefs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437333/tool-to-decipher-c-c-function-pointer-typedefs)

Comment: @JensGustedt where? I only see cdecl in that question

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To break this down yourself, start from the inner most parentheses and work your way out.

1. `(*[10])` <---- Array of 10 pointers
2. `(*[10])(int *)` <------ Array of 10 pointers to functions which has a pointer to `int` as its argument
3. `(void (*[10])(int *))` <------ Array of 10 pointers to functions which has a pointer to `int` as its argument and returns `void`
4. `(*x)(void (*[10])(int *))` <------- `x` is a pointer to a function which has as an argument (an array of 10 pointers to functions which has a pointer to int as its argument and returns `void`)

.....

I stopped partway through, but hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 10):

[cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28%2a%28%2ax%29%28void+%28%2a%5B10%5D%29%28int+%2a%29%29%29%28int+%2a%29) is very helpful for this kind of thing. It says:

declare x as pointer to function (array 10 of pointer to function (pointer to int) returning void) returning pointer to function (pointer to int) returning void

Answer (score 5):

You can find explanations here:

- [How To Read Complicated C Declarations - does not compute](http://www.kalekold.net/index.php?post=4)
- [Reading C type declarations](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html)
- [C Declarations - Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)
- [C-FAQ Question 1.21 - Complex Declarations](http://c-faq.com/decl/cdecl1.html)

Comment: @Shahbaz: What's funny about it?

Comment: I mean funny as I enjoyed it, that's why you got the +1

Comment: Never saw the declarations as a spiral!

Comment: @Shahbaz: It hadn't occurred to me either until I saw an article (3rd link) about it. It's not that complex. Convoluted (pun intended) and counter-intuitive, yes.

Comment: @deathly809 then fix it.

Comment: I was not sure if you knew where the website might have been moved to before I just deleted it, I see you did not change it either...

Comment: @deathly809 I don't own or oversee all of the Internet. :)

Answer (score 3):

> A pointer to a function which has an array of 10 pointers to functions
>   that has int * argument and return type void as argument, and returns
>   a pointer to a function which has int * argument and return type void.

[Source](http://susam.in/blog/clumsy-pointers/)

Comment: The ultimate question is, how would you go about figuring that out, if you didn't have this?

Comment: @TonyTheLion, no the questions why would someone write such a thing without breaking it down in smaller pieces?