# Typedef with function pointers in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

I'm pretty new to C, and I'm having a really hard time reading this line of code and understanding it:

```
typedef void (*getnxtbyte_t)(void *stream);
```

From looking around, I now know that it is for a pointer pointing to a function. But could anyone help me clarify this even further? What is the name of this new type? What function is it pointing to? Is the parameter of the function `(void* stream)`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see articles linked in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8249710/968261).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this C statement mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249483/what-does-this-c-statement-mean)

Answer (score 5):

*It is a tricky syntax to get used to.*

**What is the name of this new type?**

The type is `getnxtbyte_t`.  (You can read that trailing `_t` as "type".  It's a popular convention.)

A variable of type `getnxtbyte_t` can hold the address of a function that takes one `void *` parameter and has return type `void`.

**What function is it pointing to?**

Wrong question.

That code merely **defines** the type.  No variables are created so there's no "it" to point to anything.

If you know of a function with the correct signature, such as:

```
void some_func(void*) {}
```

You may now create a pointer to it using that typedef:

```
getnxtbyte_t my_function_pointer = some_func;
```

Answer (score 1):

This `typedef` creates a type called `getnxtbyte_t`. That type is for a pointer to a function that returns `void` (i.e. nothing), as shown in the second word. That function takes a single parameter, which is a `void *`, shown by `stream`.

So if you had a function with a declaration like this:

```
void some_function(void *any_name);
```

Then you could use a `typedef` like the one in your post:

```
void *some_param = NULL;
typedef void (*getnxtbyte_t)(void *stream); // declare typedef
getnxtbyte_t func = some_function; // assign
func(some_param); // call
```

Answer (score 0):

The function pointer type name is `getnxtbyte_t`. It's not pointing to anything now -- this is a *type* of pointer, not an actual pointer. It's just like saying

```
typedef struct foo {int x;} Foo;
```

you define a type `Foo`,  but no actual instance of that type. And finally, yes, the function takes a single `void*` argument, and returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to C, so if there are any errors please correct me.

---

A pointer that points to a function is formatted like so:

```
datatype (*POINTER_NAME)(PARAMETERS);
```

So that's the **data type** the pointed function returns, the **name of the pointer** and the **parameters** the pointed function takes.

Here's how a function pointer looks compared to a normal function declaration:

```
// normal function declaration
void getnxtbyte_t(void *stream);

// function pointer
void (*getnxtbyte_t)(void *stream);
```

`typedef` allows us to create our own type.

```
// will create a type called getnxtbyte_t
typedef void (*getnxtbyte_t)(void *stream);
```

At this point we have only declared a type; we are not pointing to anything. So let's create a pointer named `func_ptr` and point it to a function.

```
// func_ptr is a pointer of type getnxtbyte_t
getnxtbyte_t func_ptr = another_function;

// calling func_ptr is now the same as calling another_function
func_ptr(an_argument);

// had we not used typedef, we would type:
void (*getnxtbyte_t)(void *stream) = another_func;
getnxtbyte_t(an_argument);
```