# Meaning of complex C syntax

Tags: c++, c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this C statement mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249483/what-does-this-c-statement-mean)

What does this expression mean?

```
char *(*c[10])(int **p);
```

Comment: Try the ["clockwise/spiral rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: If they have this in their codebase your sanity will be better without that job.

Comment: Everytime I see one of these interview questions I feel like I'm reading something from a code obfuscation contest.

Comment: Such things you see exclusively in job interviews (one of the surest hint NOT to take that job) or in university exams (all of us had to pass it, mate...)

Comment: this is exactly why #golang authors [have chosen](http://blog.golang.org/2010/07/gos-declaration-syntax.html) to swap type and name in declarations.

Answer (score 77):

`c` is an array of 10 function pointers that return a `char*` and take a `int**` as an argument.

```
(*c[10])
   ^^^^ = array of 10

(*c[10])
 ^ = function pointer
```

So right now we have an array of 10 function pointers.

```
char *(*c[10])
^^^^^^ = returns a char*

char *(*c[10])(int** p)
               ^^^^^ = takes a int** as an argument
```

Array of 10 function pointers that return a `char*` and take a `int**` as an argument.

<sub>NOTE: If you write code like this you deserve to be slapped in the face.</sub>

Comment: +1 for NOTE. Typedefs plz k thx.

Comment: +1 for getting 60 upvotes in 15 hours!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with writing code like that.

Comment: @markwatson It's better to use `typedef`s.

Answer (score 52):

[cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is a nice tool to translate `C` gibberish into English

```
$ cdecl explain 'char * (*c[10]) (int **)'
declare c as array 10 of pointer to function (pointer to pointer to int) returning pointer to char
```

Comment: Gibberish was better ROTFL

Comment: also available at http://cdecl.org

Comment: I don't think it is nice at all, is very buggy and often fails to understand perfectly valid C.

Answer (score 46):

Some examples, and a *snippet* at the end that uses the decl.

### 1. Pointer to a function:

`void (*foo)(void);`

Would give you a function pointer `foo` which takes no parameters and returns nothing.

**Ex. A:**

```
void fun_1(void)
{
    ...
}

foo = fun_1;
foo(); /* this would call fun_1() */
```

**Ex. B:**

`char (*bar)(int);`

Would give you a function pointer `bar` which takes 1 parameter as integer and return a `char`.

```
char fun_2(int x)
{
    if (x == 50)
        return 'a';
    return 'Z';
}

char v;
bar = fun_2;
v = bar(50); /* this would call fun_2() with 50 as parameter and return 'a' */
```

### 2. Pointer to a pointer

`int **p;` is a pointer that points to a pointer of type int.

**Ex. C:**

```
int y[3] = {4, 3, 6};
int *w = &y[0];
int **z = &w;

printf("print: %d ", **z);
printf("%d ", *++(*z));
printf("%d\n", *(*z+1));
```

`print: 4 3 6`

### 3. Function returning a pointer

**Ex. D:**

```
char *zez(char *s)
{
    s = "def";
    return s;
}


char *str = "abc";

printf("%s - ", str);
printf("%s\n", zez(str));
```

`abc - def`

### 4. Function pointer to a function returning a pointer

Creating a function pointer to `zez()`

**Ex. E:**

```
char *(*ptr_zez)(char *);

ptr_zez = zez;

printf("ptr: %s - ", str);
printf("%s\n", ptr_zez(str));
```

`ptr: abc - def`

### 5. Array of function pointers, to function returning a char pointer, taking a char pointer

**Ex. F:**

```
char *(*c[10])(char *);

c[0] = zez;

printf("c[0]: %s - ", str);
printf("%s\n", c[0](str));
```

`c[0]: abc - def`

### 6. "Declare c as array 10 of pointer to function (pointer to pointer to int) returning pointer to char"

```
char *cumlade(int **p)
{
    char *c;
    int i;

    if ((c = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to reserve 7 bytes\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        c[i] = (unsigned char)*(*p+i);
    }
    c[6] = '\0';

    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    int t[3][3] = {{97 ,98, 99}, {100, 101, 102}};
    int *u = &t[0][0];
    int **v = &u;
    char *ex;
    char *(*c[10])(int **p); /* <-- the fun */

    c[0] = cumlade;
    c[1] = cumlade;    

    ex = c[0](v);
    printf("EX: %s\n", ex);
    free(ex);

    ex = c[1](v);
    printf("AX: %s\n", ex);
    free(ex);

    return 0;
}
```

`EX: abcdef`
`AX: abcdef`

Comment: +1 This is a brilliant answer.

Comment: This is one of the most thorough and understandable explanations I've ever seen.

Answer (score 12):

`c` is an array of `10` pointers to functions taking a pointer to pointer to `int` as its parameter and returning a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 8):

Type declaration involves three operators: array `[SIZE]`, pointer `*` and function `(type1 param1, type2 param2, ...)`. Remember that **all the three operators are right-associative**.

```
char *(*c[10])(int **p);
```

Let's add more parenthesis to make the associativity more clear.

```
char *((*(c[10]))(int *(*p)))
```

Start from `c`, the variable.

`c[10]` means "c is an array of 10 elements, but each element is a ..."

Then see the `*` beside it. `*(c[10])` means "c is an array of 10 elements, each element is a pointer pointing to ..."

Then `(*(c[10]))(int *(*p))` means "c is an array of 10 elements, each element is a pointer to a function, which returns ..." Using similar methods we see the function takes one parameter which is "a pointer to a pointer to an int".

Then `*((*(c[10]))(int *(*p)))` means "c is an array of 10 elements, each element is a pointer to a function, which returns a pointer to a ..."

Finally `char *((*(c[10]))(int *(*p)))` means "c is an array of 10 elements, each element is a pointer to a function, which returns a pointer to a char". That's it.

I find the *Clockwise/Spiral Rule* very useful. See http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

But I'd rather add more brackets than using spirals.

Comment: +1 for the Clockwise/Spiral Rule. This is the first time I am hearing of it

Answer (score 5):

ok now the answer you have, it is an array of function pointer, but is there clean(er) way to write code like this? Yes there is, and I am sure this code might be understood at the first glance:

```
typedef char *(*weirdFuncPtr)(int **p);
weirdFuncPtr funcPtrArray[10];
```

Btw. usually I avoid typdefs - I use them when declaring function pointers though. This makes it easier to understand this sort of C code (C is an abbreviation for Cryptic, is it?)

Comment: Good advise. _Always_ use typedef when using function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It declares an array of function pointers. There are 10 elements in the array (from c[10] part of the declaration). the function to which these pointers can point will return char* and takes only one parameter i.e pointer to pointer to integer (int **p)

Take a look at the first answer to this question [How can I use an array of function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/how-to-use-array-of-function-pointers)
there you will find another example of declaring function-pointer array and it may end your confusion.

Comment: I guess this is the best answer!! and the least voted one!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for intuitive explanation for this, 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/16841

They explained this using postfix order evaluation, just like expression evaluation.