# What does the macro ((void(*)())0)() mean?

Tags: c++, c, macros

The outcome of the following macro is clear:

```
#define CRASH() do {\
  *(int *)(uintptr_t)0xbbadbeef = 0;\
  ((void(*)())0)();\
} while (false)
```

My question is, what does the line

```
((void(*)())0)();
```

break down to, in English? For example, "this is a function that returns a pointer to a...."

Comment: Note: there is a trailing backslash missing on the 3rd line.

Comment: @wildplasser On the first one too.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q75MZws4ltw#t=1m27s

Comment: The expression has different meanings in C and in C++. The empty parenthesis in C mean ... function taking unspecified, but fixed, arguments. In C++ they mean ... function taking no arguments (*like `fx(void)` in C*).

Comment: @pmg I think it will crash and burn no matter...

Comment: It means the person is trying to confuse the person doing maintenance a year down the road. Perhaps the programmer has *job security* issues

Comment: Btw there are far more creative ways to crash the program. How about `for(char* ptr=0; true; ptr++) *ptr = 0xAA;` or `size_t max=0; max = ~max; while(malloc(max));` or `free((void*)&main);` or `int main(){return main();}.`  (Stricly, some of them aren't allowed by C, but fun none the less. Don't try this at home.)

Comment: @Ed heal: there is nothing wrong with this way of crawbar crashing. Sometimes one can have a reason not to call exit() _exit() or abort(). And there might be platforms/occasions where dereferencing the deadbeef pointer does not cause a crash/exception, so the third line *could* be useful after all.

Comment: @wildplasser - I disagree - code should be easy to understand from the outset. Why not just raise a signal on your own process - simple, easy to understand and effective. You can even get a debugger to catch them. Please tell me what reason for a convoluted method to be adopted?

Comment: @Ed Heal: signals could be unavailable, masked, or unwanted. Maybe the macro has to be callable *from within* a signal handler. Who knows? BTW: if a debugger+watchpoints are available, setting a watchpoint on 0xdeadbeef will be a catch-all, and the stacktrace will hopefully do the rest. Also: using a dbugger, there is a possibility to jump out of this fragment and continue execution. You can't escape from an abort().

Comment: I just think that the code is unreadable and there are better solutions that this convoluted method. I see that you have offered not a reasonable reason for doing this.

Comment: Since you don't know the context (neither do I), you cannot prove that there is a better method. There could be. Or there could be not. Also: the above code is *not* unreadable. Even if you don't understand how it works, you can still read it, and know what it does (or is supposed to do). Do you understand your debugger's source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this C statement mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249483/what-does-this-c-statement-mean)

Comment: @BoBTFish OWBWebkit source. People may criticize the readability, but the macro name is clear enough. Might as well have some fun with forcing an app to crash:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like it casts `0` as a function pointer (with the signature that it takes not parameters and has void return type) and then invokes it.

```
(     (            void(*)()                  ) 0       )      ();
  /* cast..*/ /* fn pointer signature */  /*..cast 0 */  /* invocation */
```

Which is another way to say that it's trying to invoke (call) a function that's expected to be located in memory at address 0x00000000 - which is guaranteed to be an invalid address.

Answer (score 3):

- Cast `0` to a pointer to a `void` function that <strike>takes</strike> can be called with no parameters (the `(void(*)())0` part of the expression)
- Call that function through a pointer with an empty parameter list (the `()` part after it).

**EDIT 1**: Edited in response to Cristoph's comment.

Comment: C vs C++ strikes again: in C++, an empty parameter list means the function takes no arguments; in C, that's only the case for definitions - in general, an empty parameter list means that the function takes an unspecified number of non-variadic arguments subject to default argument promotion

Comment: @Christoph Darn it! Well, at least in this case fixing the answer required significantly less effort.

Answer (score 2):

It casts 0 to a function pointer, where the function takes no argument and returns void, then tries to call this function. It basically dereferences a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It casts a `NULL` pointer to a method taking no parameters and returning `void`, and attempts to call this method.

Needless to say, it crashes, so the name `CRASH` suits it very well.

Answer (score 0):

It casts 0 to a pointer to a function, then attempts to call that function. Which will cause a segfault and crash.

Edit: way too much competition for these questions. Upvotes all round, and I'm going to bed :)

Answer (score 0):

It means “treating NULL pointer as pointer to `void function()`, call `function()`”.

Answer (score 0):

It takes the value zero, and casts it to a function pointer that doesn't return anything (void).

Presumably, the purpose is that when you call this "function", it calls address zero, which should indeed crash the application.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is simpler to translate to a different C++, rather than directly to english:

```
typedef void (void_func_t)();       // type of a function taking no arguments 
                                    // and returning void
typedef void_fnct_t* void_func_ptr; // pointer to such a function
static_cast<void_func_ptr>(0)();    // call that function
// ((void_func_ptr)0)();            // pure C equivalent cast
```

Comment: Won't the static cast throw an exception and prevent the program from crashing?

Comment: @Lundin: `static_cast` **never** throws exceptions. **dynamic_cast** can throw exceptions, but it cannot be used with function pointers, and it will *only* throw when casting references.

Answer (score 0):

if fp is a pointer to a function, *fp is the function itself, so(*fp)()is the way to invoke it. ANSI C permits this to be abbreviated as fp(), bu keep in mind that it is only an abbreviation.      -------C traps an pitfalls.
(  ( void(*)() )0  ) () is the avvreviation of (  *( void(*)() )0 )()