# Understanding of C programming syntax

Tags: c

i came across this syntax and i am not able to know how to start understanding this.

How to start decoding of such piece of c programming code.

```
(*(void(*)())0)();
```

i have tried to compile this code and it compile without any warning or error. SO it seems valid syntax of c programming.

Comment: @MarounMaroun; This is the best example where cdecl.org fail.

Comment: @MarounMaroun i know about that tool and tried also that it shows syntax error. Tried to break this code in this tool but no help

Comment: @haccks oh, it really fails.. I didn't try before.

Comment: This makes a null function pointer and then calls it (undefined behaviour)

Comment: @MarounMaroun; That's why I do not suggest any one to use it. It has many flaws.

Comment: Why so hurry to understand such a useless piece of code.

Comment: Could have been used in the past when the bootstrap code what at address `0` to reboot the machine.

Comment: Calling a function at address 0 requires no such grammar nonsense.

Comment: Related: [In what machine can (\* (void (\*)()) 0)() be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22248508)

Comment: Related: [What does the macro ((void(\*)())0)() mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9825255)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break it as follows:

- `(void(*)())` represents a cast of `0`. Here its is a pointer to a function with return type `void` and can have any number of arguments.

  ```
     (  void  (*)  ( )  )
         ^     ^    ^
         |     |    |
         |     |    |
         |     |    |
         |     |    |
         +     |    +
  Return type  |    Function
               |
            Pointer
  ```
- `*(void(*)())0` is dereferencing the address `0x00000000`. I think its a function address there.
- `(*(void(*)())0)();` call the function.

Comment: Aftrer reading 5 times your answer now it seems i could understood it.. Please add some more text to understand it faster way..

Comment: at address 0 what function would be there? if no function then segmentation fault or what ever written at that memory it will execute that right?

Comment: @JeegarPatel; Yes. There may be code related to boot.

Comment: @JeegarPatel If you're programming at the hardware level then whatever function is at address 0 is whatever happens to be there -- or no function at all. Some hardware might not even allow you to reference that address.

Comment: @haccks So here in your step1,, Missing function pointer name and no  arguments makes this code to confusing here.

Comment: @JeegarPatel; Pointer is confusing to me too :)

Comment: Casting a null pointer constant to a pointer produces a *null pointer*. This might not represent address zero.  So "dereferencing whatever be at 0" is not a good description.

Comment: "represents a cast to 0" -> "represents a cast *of* `0`"

Comment: @M.M; Or it might [represent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089896/null-function-pointers?lq=1#comment21242366_15090036).