# Pointer to an array of pointers is it?

Tags: c

can some one interpret the below line:

```
const void *const *ptr;
```

is it both the type & Ptr variable is constant?

Comment: You might find the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) helpful.

Comment: That [declares ptr as pointer to const pointer to const void](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+void+*const+*p%3B)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this C statement mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249483/what-does-this-c-statement-mean)

Answer (score 2):

After

```
const void *const *ptr;
```

You **can** change `ptr`, but not `*ptr`, or `**ptr`

```
ptr = <SOMETHING_ELSE>; /* ok */
*ptr = <SOMETHING_ELSE>; /* error */
**ptr = <SOMETHING_ELSE>; /* error, ignoring the point that you cannot even have an object of type void */
```

Comment: `const` or not, well you'll have an error dereferencing the pointers anyway (`**ptr`), because it's a pointer to an incomplete type. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my mind:

```
void * const var;    // The pointer is constant and var can change
const void * var;    // The pointer can change but not var
```

so I would think that your syntax

```
const void * const *ptr;
```

means that ptr is a pointer to a pointer. So ptr would point to an address and that address cannot change (the first const). Also the address that ptr is located cannot change (the second const). But I am not totally sure of this.