# What did GCC do to the statement of int *a = {1,2,3,4,5}?

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int *a = {1,2,3,4,5};
  printf("a:%x &a:%x\n",a,&a);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled this program with GCC.
The output of `a` is `1`, and the output of `&a` is an address.
What GCC did to `int *a = {1,2,3,4,5}`? Did GCC treat it as an array or a pointer that points to an array or something else?

Comment: don't post pictures of code, post the actual code.

Comment: Not because we can't read image of code, but because they are code and should be posted as such. Someone may also want to copy-and-paste it to run it.

Comment: [Array automatically decay into pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) in most cases. <--- possible dupe

Comment: `int *a = {1,2,3,4,5};`  really?

Comment: comma works as an operator here. that's why you get a=1 as a={1,2,3,4,5}  becomes equivalent to “(a = 1),2,3,4,5" . and *a is pointing to an integer.

Comment: A pointer to an integer can also be a pointer to the first element of an array. The compiler definitely won't just ignore curly braces. This is not the problem.

Comment: @Pusku there is no comma operator inside curly braces

Comment: @user202729 there are no arrays in this code

Comment: After some "what does this code do" like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603286/how-is-int-main-valid-c) it gets quickly boring. In particular this case the compiler basically already explained it.

Answer (score 1):

I did not refer to the C standards but you can see how `gcc` handles this from the compile warning messages:

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.c
int main()
{
    int * a = {1, 2};
    return !!a;
}
[STEP 102] # gcc -Wall foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:3:16: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer
without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     int * a = {1, 2};
                ^
foo.c:3:16: note: (near initialization for ‘a’)
foo.c:3:19: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
     int * a = {1, 2};
                   ^
foo.c:3:19: note: (near initialization for ‘a’)
[STEP 103] #
```

**UPDATE:**

Just took a look at the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/standards) and found this in section *6.7.8 Initialization*:

> The initializer for a **scalar** shall be a single expression, **optionally enclosed in braces.**

Answer (score 1):

The code is a constraint violation as an initializer for a non-aggregate can only contain 1 element.

GCC has an "extension" to ignore excess initializers, so it treats the code as `int *p = 1;`.  This is also a constraint violation, because an integer cannot be assigned to a pointer. But gcc has another "extension" to treat such code as `int *p = (int *)1;`.  So you end up with a pointer to address 1.

> and the output of &a is an address.

`&a` is the address in memory of the variable `a`, this has nothing to do with what value is stored in `a`.