# In what machine can (* (void (*)()) 0)() be used?

Tags: c

C traps and pitfalls 2.1
I thought 0 is always invalid address. How could he put a function in that position?

Answer (score 5):

It's architecture dependent.

From the book:

I
once
talked
to
someone
who
was
writing
a
C
program
that
was
going
to
run
stand-alone
in
a
small
microprocessor (**answer right here**).
When
this
machine
was
switched
on,
the
hardware
would
call
the
subroutine
whose
address
was
stored
in
location
0.
In
order
to
simulate
turning
power
on,
we
had
to
devise
a
C
statement
that
would
call
this
subroutine
explicitly.
After
some
thought,
we
came
up
with
the
following:

```
(*(void(*)())0)();
```

Comment: But 0 is always invalid. I got confused

Comment: that's not true, *as I said*, it's architecture dependent. for example, it was valid on my C64: http://sta.c64.org/cbm64mem.html

Comment: your *intuition* is right though. it's not a good idea to allow it, as it prevents catching null pointer dereference.

Comment: 0 is not always invalid, just like it is not always the address component (i mean where it points to) of a null pointer. null pointer is something whose address is never equal to address of something else. (like a function or an object. standard explains it much nicer, however i am too lazy to find it now). So there might be some systems where 0 is perfectly valid address and null is just something else (it could be anything). by the way allowing access to address 0 not necessarily prevents catching null pointer dereference.

Comment: As an aside, jumping to the restart vector does not, in general, simulate power-on as the peripheral devices do not get reset to their power-on state.  It's more usual, with modern controllers, to force a watchdog timer reset which does perform peripheral device initialization.

Answer (score 1):

For microprocessors/microcontrollers, you have raw access to any RAM/Flash Address unless prohibited in hardware. Therefore accessing address `0` in microprocessor is completely vaild.

Answer (score 0):

I think that  `(* (void (*)()) 0)` means that it is trying to invoke a function that is located in memory at address `0x00000000`(*which probably is an invalid address*)

A very similar question on stackoverflow [What does this C statement mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249483/what-does-this-c-statement-mean) may help

Comment: There's no invocation, that would require more `()`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey:- Yes actually Karoly explained it, its C vs C++ strikes again: in C++, an empty parameter list means the function takes no arguments; in C, that's only the case for definitions - in general, an empty parameter list means that the function takes an unspecified number of non-variadic arguments subject to default argument promotion. Kindly do correct me if I am missing something

Comment: eh..I am so sorry that i missed the ()...my question is that i thought 0 is invalid