# What does  double* (*p[3]) (void* (*)()); mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I am having difficulty trying to understand what the following declaration means. Is this declaration standard?

```
double* (*p[3]) (void* (*)());
```

Can anyone help me to understand the meaning of this declaration?

Comment: I'm glad to walk in the Java world ...

Comment: ...as opposed to running in the C world ? ;-)

Comment: Oli Charlesworth provided a generically useful answer. Don't close.

Comment: Should probably be closed as a duplicate, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437333/tool-to-decipher-c-c-function-pointer-typedefs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rule for reading hairy declarations: find the leftmost identifier and work outward, remembering that `()` and `[]` bind before `*`, so `T *a[N]` is an array of pointers to `T`, `T (*a)[N]` is a pointer to an array of `T`, `T *f()` is a function returning a pointer to `T`, and `T (*f)()` is a pointer to a function returning T.  Since a function prototype may omit parameter names, you may see things like `T *[N]` or `T (*)()`.  The meaning is mostly the same<sup>1</sup>, just pretend that there's an identifier of 0 length.

Thus,

```
          p                      -- p
          p[3]                   -- is a 3-element array
         *p[3]                   -- of pointers
        (*p[3]) (           )    -- to functions
        (*p[3]) (      (*)())    --   taking a pointer to a function
        (*p[3]) (    * (*)())    --   returning a pointer
        (*p[3]) (void* (*)())    --   to void
      * (*p[3]) (void* (*)())    -- returning a pointer
double* (*p[3]) (void* (*)());   -- to double
```

The important thing to take away here is that you are declaring `p` as an *array* of `...`, not a function returning `...`.

What would such a beast look like in practice?  Well, first, you need three functions to point to.  Each of these functions takes a single parameter, which is a pointer to a function returning a pointer to void:

```
double *foo(void *(*)());
double *bar(void *(*)());
double *bletch(void *(*)());

double *(*p[3]) (void *(*)()) = {foo, bar, bletch};
```

Each of `foo`, `bar`, and `bletch` would call the function passed to it and somehow return a pointer to `double`.

You would also want to define one or more functions that satisfy the parameter type for each of `foo`, `bar`, and `bletch`:

```
void *blurga() {...}
```

so if you called `foo` directly, you'd call it like

```
double *pv;
...
pv = foo(blurga);
```

So we could imagine a call like

```
double *pv = (*p[0])(blurga);
```

---

<sup>1 - the difference is that in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are identical to `T *a`; in all three cases, `a` is a *pointer to* `T`, not an array of `T`.  Note that this is *only* true in a function parameter declaration.  Thus, `T *[]` will be identical to `T **`.</sup>

Answer (score 10):

Just use http://cdecl.org:

> declare p as array 3 of pointer to function (pointer to function returning pointer to void) returning pointer to double

For more info, see this MSDN article: [*Interpreting more complex declarators*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x82y1z4.aspx).

But typedefs would help:

```
typedef void *(*foo)();         // foo is a function-pointer type
typedef double *(*bar)(foo);    // bar is also a function-pointer type
bar p[3];
```

(Obviously, use appropriate names in place of `foo` and `bar`!)

Comment: I have never seen that site before +1

Comment: +1 for linking the source of your wisdom instead of making it look as if you conjured it up yourself. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar - Not fair to assume that cdecl is the only way for everyone to understand a difficult looking C declaration.

Comment: ...within one minute of the question? It's not a shame either, I don't think I ever unscrambled a function pointer declaration *without* cdecl.

Comment: @DevSolar: To be fair, once one has memorised the "algorithm" (as described in the article I linked to), doing this manually is not a problem.

Comment: +1 for the site! Will be helpful for many people in the future :-).

Answer (score 2):

Your `p` is an *array of 3 pointers* to a function returning a `double` pointer, and taking as argument a pointer to another function that returns a `void` pointer and that takes no arguments.

But, **don't use this syntax**, try using typedef instead.

Comment: Me too but I like Oli's link which "proverbially taught me to fish" :)

Answer (score 1):

It is array (of size 3) of function pointers which returns pointer to double and take another function pointer as argument.

Type of function whose pointer can be stored in the array:  `double *(func)(void* (*)())` 
 
Type of function whose pointer can be passed as argument to func: `void *(func1)(void)`

Comment: +1 because this is the most easily understood description (for me).

Answer (score 0):

"There is a technique known as the ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule'' which enables any C programmer to parse in their head any C declaration!"

Clockwise Spiral Rule - http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html